# Spring Boot Thymeleaf - Error resolving template [...page], template might not exist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

For POC purposes we work with Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot configuration.

Can you help me solving this error:

> **Error resolving template [chatloginpage], template might not exist or
> might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.**

This happens when navigating to localhost:8080/chatstart. Of course I looked to different stackoverflow answers.

Working with Spring Boot requires no additional confiruation. The html pages can be put in the templates folder and no WEB-INF is needed.
This error may be due to working with Rest services as well?

The pom.xml contains:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The main controller is for this non-REST part is:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class StartChatController {

    @RequestMapping( path = "/chatstart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
        if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/chatlogin";
        }
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        return "chatting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/chatlogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "chatloginpage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/chatlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String username) {
        username = username.trim();
        if (username.isEmpty()) {
            return "chatloginpage";
        }
        request.getSession().setAttribute("username", username);
        return "redirect:/chatstart";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/chatlogout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.getSession(true).invalidate();
        return "redirect:/chatlogin";
    }
}
```

All web page resources are under resources:

```
main.css ... for brevity not shown
main.js ... for brevity not shown
```

The resources/templates/chatloginpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login-container">
        <h1 class="title">Enter your username</h1>
        <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <button action="chatlogin" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The resources/templates/chatting.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Spring Boot WebSocket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chat-container">
    <div class="chat-header">
        <div class="user-container">
            <span id="username" th:utext="${username}"></span>
            <a th:href="@{/chatlogout}">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <h3>Spring WebSocket Chat Demo</h3>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="connecting">Connecting...</div>
    <ul id="messageArea">
    </ul>
    <form id="messageForm" name="messageForm">
        <div class="input-message">
            <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off"
                   placeholder="Type a message..."/>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script href="../main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which directory you store the templates?

Comment: See above, as an example ... "The resources/templates/chatting.html page" (so, resources/templates). Below is the solution of the problem.

Comment: Use ```resources/templates``` for templates and ```resources/static``` for ```css``` and ```js``` files. This is the standard for Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. No configuration needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple.

**Without Spring Boot** often Thymeleaf templates are put under resources/static/templates. You see it in many examples.

**With Spring Boot** the default location is resources/templates. So, no 'static' folder!

To use in Spring Boot the resources/static/template location, just add to the appliction.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static/templates/
```