# Problem importing and running (upgraded) Spring Boot 3 / Thymeleaf zipped Eclipse project

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, thymeleaf

I have a set of programming examples I use for a class I teach on Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I provide these to my students as zipped Eclipse project files. I recently upgraded these from Spring Boot 2 using Java 11 to Spring Boot 3 using Java 17. The programs work correctly.

However, there's an annoying issue with the zipped Eclipse projects. I export the projects using Eclipse Export -> Archive File. When I reimport the files and run them, I get an error:

*Error resolving template [], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers*

When I run Project -> Update Maven Project, it fixes the issue. However, this step should not be necessary. It was not required with Spring Boot 2. Any thoughts?

Here's the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>edu.cscc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProfilesDemoWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProfilesDemoWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I fix the problem by running Maven Update and re-export the project and then import it - the template resolve error is back.

I originally upgraded the projects by modifying and rerunning the pom.xml file. I've tried rebuilding the project using Spring Initializr to create a starter project and then adding the existing code in Eclipse. In either case, I get the template error (which can be resolved by rerunning maven).

I tried upgrading Eclipse from 2023-06 to 2023-09 and that had no effect.

Comment: "When I reimport the files and run them, I get an error: Error resolving template []" sounds expected as Eclipse does not export dynamic dependencies so a rebuild/update is expected after importing the project. Try to compare a working and a broken project to spot missing files or configurations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434885/2834978